# How do I install python's httplib2 on a mac?

Tags: python, macos, installation, pydev, httplib2

```
OS: Mac OSx 10.8.3
IDE: Eclipse w/ PyDev
```

How do I properly install [httplib2](https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) on a Mac? It can be done on Ubuntu, Debian, Gentoo, and FreeBSD via the command posted below except Mac OS.

Apparently this command will work but my Terminal says it can't find setup.py.

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:

1. Download httplib2 onto your computer
2. `cd` into the directory when you unpacked httplib2
3. Run the command there

Alternately, you can run:

```
~$ python /path/to/httplib2/setup.py install
```

from anywhere.

Please note that this will install httplib2 into your system's Python (unless you have done something to change what `python` is pointing to).  You may want to look at Python's virtual environments and `pip` (PIP Installs Python) tool for managing your dependencies without changing your system Python.

Comment: Great Post!  I used the following to pull down 0.91  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httplib2